# MySQL doesn't work with libmysqlclient

Tags: debian, mysql

```
Mysql is on
libmysqlclient: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.21
dlopen error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.21: invalid ELF header
ERROR loading mysql = /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.21
```

Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Comment: Looks like you have different versions of things installed. How did you install MySQL and libmysqlclient?

Comment: That's the server is on support at the company I work, so all the installation was made there before me.
Colleague adviced me the next solution
`apt install libmysqlclient21`
and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The way I was able to resolve the issue:

```
apt install libmysqlclient21
```

Comment: If that is what was required, then I would seriously ask why that had to be done? I would argue that someone has screwed up & I would ask what other damage has been done?

Comment: Or, what you just screwed up – there clearly was an installation that expected a different version, and whatever was there aside from the program you tried to use now will probably find the version that you installed this way.

Comment: libmysqlclient21 is not available in Debian 11, but currently only in Debian sid. It depends on libc6 >= 2.34, while Debian 11 provides libc6 ~ 2.31. I guess it's not a Debian 11 system anymore (or else the package is provided by an external repository, maybe Oracle's).